# Catkin build fails when a lambda is added to it

Tags: c++, lambda, ros

```cpp
 rand_dat1_sub_handle = node.subscribe<geometry_msgs::Vector3>(
        "random/data1", 100,
        [](geometry_msgs::Vector3::ConstPtr& data){std::cout<<data->x;});

  rand_dat2_sub_handle = node.subscribe<geometry_msgs::Vector3>(
        "random/data2", 100,
        [](geometry_msgs::Vector3::ConstPtr& data){std::cout<<data->x;});
```

when I use the above block of code in my class definition script, my build fails giving me the following errors.

```
In file included from /usr/include/boost/function/detail/maybe_include.hpp:18:0,
                 from /usr/include/boost/function/detail/function_iterate.hpp:14,
                 from /usr/include/boost/preprocessor/iteration/detail/iter/forward1.hpp:52,
                 from /usr/include/boost/function.hpp:64,
                 from /opt/ros/melodic/include/ros/forwards.h:40,
                 from /opt/ros/melodic/include/ros/common.h:37,
                 from /opt/ros/melodic/include/ros/ros.h:43,
                 from /home/hari/workspace/catkin_ws/src/gui_pkg/src/tcpserver.h:7,
                 from /home/hari/workspace/catkin_ws/src/gui_pkg/src/tcpserver.cpp:2:
/usr/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp: In instantiation of ‘static void boost::detail::function::void_function_obj_invoker1<FunctionObj, R, T0>::invoke(boost::detail::function::function_buffer&, T0) [with FunctionObj = TCPServer::TCPServer(ros::NodeHandle*, QObject*)::<lambda(geometry_msgs::Vector3_<std::allocator<void> >::ConstPtr&)>; R = void; T0 = const boost::shared_ptr<const geometry_msgs::Vector3_<std::allocator<void> > >&]’:
/usr/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:925:38:   required from ‘void boost::function1<R, T1>::assign_to(Functor) [with Functor = TCPServer::TCPServer(ros::NodeHandle*, QObject*)::<lambda(geometry_msgs::Vector3_<std::allocator<void> >::ConstPtr&)>; R = void; T0 = const boost::shared_ptr<const geometry_msgs::Vector3_<std::allocator<void> > >&]’
/usr/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:716:7:   required from ‘boost::function1<R, T1>::function1(Functor, typename boost::enable_if_c<(! boost::is_integral<Functor>::value), int>::type) [with Functor = TCPServer::TCPServer(ros::NodeHandle*, QObject*)::<lambda(geometry_msgs::Vector3_<std::allocator<void> >::ConstPtr&)>; R = void; T0 = const boost::shared_ptr<const geometry_msgs::Vector3_<std::allocator<void> > >&; typename boost::enable_if_c<(! boost::is_integral<Functor>::value), int>::type = int]’
/usr/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:1061:16:   required from ‘boost::function<R(T0)>::function(Functor, typename boost::enable_if_c<(! boost::is_integral<Functor>::value), int>::type) [with Functor = TCPServer::TCPServer(ros::NodeHandle*, QObject*)::<lambda(geometry_msgs::Vector3_<std::allocator<void> >::ConstPtr&)>; R = void; T0 = const boost::shared_ptr<const geometry_msgs::Vector3_<std::allocator<void> > >&; typename boost::enable_if_c<(! boost::is_integral<Functor>::value), int>::type = int]’
/home/hari/workspace/catkin_ws/src/gui_pkg/src/tcpserver.cpp:85:83:   required from here
/usr/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:159:11: error: no match for call to ‘(TCPServer::TCPServer(ros::NodeHandle*, QObject*)::<lambda(geometry_msgs::Vector3_<std::allocator<void> >::ConstPtr&)>) (const boost::shared_ptr<const geometry_msgs::Vector3_<std::allocator<void> > >&)’
           BOOST_FUNCTION_RETURN((*f)(BOOST_FUNCTION_ARGS));
           ^
/usr/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:159:11: note: candidate: void (*)(geometry_msgs::Vector3_<std::allocator<void> >::ConstPtr&) {aka void (*)(boost::shared_ptr<const geometry_msgs::Vector3_<std::allocator<void> > >&)} <conversion>
/usr/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:159:11: note:   conversion of argument 2 would be ill-formed:
/usr/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:159:11: error: binding reference of type ‘geometry_msgs::Vector3_<std::allocator<void> >::ConstPtr& {aka boost::shared_ptr<const geometry_msgs::Vector3_<std::allocator<void> > >&}’ to ‘const boost::shared_ptr<const geometry_msgs::Vector3_<std::allocator<void> > >’ discards qualifiers
/home/hari/workspace/catkin_ws/src/gui_pkg/src/tcpserver.cpp:85:50: note: candidate: TCPServer::TCPServer(ros::NodeHandle*, QObject*)::<lambda(geometry_msgs::Vector3_<std::allocator<void> >::ConstPtr&)> <near match>
         [](geometry_msgs::Vector3::ConstPtr& data){std::cout<<data->x<<std::endl;});
                                                  ^
/home/hari/workspace/catkin_ws/src/gui_pkg/src/tcpserver.cpp:85:50: note:   conversion of argument 1 would be ill-formed:
In file included from /usr/include/boost/function/detail/maybe_include.hpp:18:0,
                 from /usr/include/boost/function/detail/function_iterate.hpp:14,
                 from /usr/include/boost/preprocessor/iteration/detail/iter/forward1.hpp:52,
                 from /usr/include/boost/function.hpp:64,
                 from /opt/ros/melodic/include/ros/forwards.h:40,
                 from /opt/ros/melodic/include/ros/common.h:37,
                 from /opt/ros/melodic/include/ros/ros.h:43,
                 from /home/hari/workspace/catkin_ws/src/gui_pkg/src/tcpserver.h:7,
                 from /home/hari/workspace/catkin_ws/src/gui_pkg/src/tcpserver.cpp:2:
/usr/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:159:11: error: binding reference of type ‘geometry_msgs::Vector3_<std::allocator<void> >::ConstPtr& {aka boost::shared_ptr<const geometry_msgs::Vector3_<std::allocator<void> > >&}’ to ‘const boost::shared_ptr<const geometry_msgs::Vector3_<std::allocator<void> > >’ discards qualifiers
           BOOST_FUNCTION_RETURN((*f)(BOOST_FUNCTION_ARGS));
           ^
/usr/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp: In instantiation of ‘static void boost::detail::function::void_function_obj_invoker1<FunctionObj, R, T0>::invoke(boost::detail::function::function_buffer&, T0) [with FunctionObj = TCPServer::TCPServer(ros::NodeHandle*, QObject*)::<lambda(geometry_msgs::Vector3_<std::allocator<void> >::ConstPtr&)>; R = void; T0 = const boost::shared_ptr<const geometry_msgs::Vector3_<std::allocator<void> > >&]’:
/usr/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:925:38:   required from ‘void boost::function1<R, T1>::assign_to(Functor) [with Functor = TCPServer::TCPServer(ros::NodeHandle*, QObject*)::<lambda(geometry_msgs::Vector3_<std::allocator<void> >::ConstPtr&)>; R = void; T0 = const boost::shared_ptr<const geometry_msgs::Vector3_<std::allocator<void> > >&]’
/usr/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:716:7:   required from ‘boost::function1<R, T1>::function1(Functor, typename boost::enable_if_c<(! boost::is_integral<Functor>::value), int>::type) [with Functor = TCPServer::TCPServer(ros::NodeHandle*, QObject*)::<lambda(geometry_msgs::Vector3_<std::allocator<void> >::ConstPtr&)>; R = void; T0 = const boost::shared_ptr<const geometry_msgs::Vector3_<std::allocator<void> > >&; typename boost::enable_if_c<(! boost::is_integral<Functor>::value), int>::type = int]’
/usr/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:1061:16:   required from ‘boost::function<R(T0)>::function(Functor, typename boost::enable_if_c<(! boost::is_integral<Functor>::value), int>::type) [with Functor = TCPServer::TCPServer(ros::NodeHandle*, QObject*)::<lambda(geometry_msgs::Vector3_<std::allocator<void> >::ConstPtr&)>; R = void; T0 = const boost::shared_ptr<const geometry_msgs::Vector3_<std::allocator<void> > >&; typename boost::enable_if_c<(! boost::is_integral<Functor>::value), int>::type = int]’
/home/hari/workspace/catkin_ws/src/gui_pkg/src/tcpserver.cpp:89:83:   required from here
/usr/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:159:11: error: no match for call to ‘(TCPServer::TCPServer(ros::NodeHandle*, QObject*)::<lambda(geometry_msgs::Vector3_<std::allocator<void> >::ConstPtr&)>) (const boost::shared_ptr<const geometry_msgs::Vector3_<std::allocator<void> > >&)’
/usr/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:159:11: note: candidate: void (*)(geometry_msgs::Vector3_<std::allocator<void> >::ConstPtr&) {aka void (*)(boost::shared_ptr<const geometry_msgs::Vector3_<std::allocator<void> > >&)} <conversion>
/usr/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:159:11: note:   conversion of argument 2 would be ill-formed:
/usr/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:159:11: error: binding reference of type ‘geometry_msgs::Vector3_<std::allocator<void> >::ConstPtr& {aka boost::shared_ptr<const geometry_msgs::Vector3_<std::allocator<void> > >&}’ to ‘const boost::shared_ptr<const geometry_msgs::Vector3_<std::allocator<void> > >’ discards qualifiers
/home/hari/workspace/catkin_ws/src/gui_pkg/src/tcpserver.cpp:89:50: note: candidate: TCPServer::TCPServer(ros::NodeHandle*, QObject*)::<lambda(geometry_msgs::Vector3_<std::allocator<void> >::ConstPtr&)> <near match>
         [](geometry_msgs::Vector3::ConstPtr& data){std::cout<<data->x<<std::endl;});
                                                  ^
/home/hari/workspace/catkin_ws/src/gui_pkg/src/tcpserver.cpp:89:50: note:   conversion of argument 1 would be ill-formed:
In file included from /usr/include/boost/function/detail/maybe_include.hpp:18:0,
                 from /usr/include/boost/function/detail/function_iterate.hpp:14,
                 from /usr/include/boost/preprocessor/iteration/detail/iter/forward1.hpp:52,
                 from /usr/include/boost/function.hpp:64,
                 from /opt/ros/melodic/include/ros/forwards.h:40,
                 from /opt/ros/melodic/include/ros/common.h:37,
                 from /opt/ros/melodic/include/ros/ros.h:43,
                 from /home/hari/workspace/catkin_ws/src/gui_pkg/src/tcpserver.h:7,
                 from /home/hari/workspace/catkin_ws/src/gui_pkg/src/tcpserver.cpp:2:
/usr/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:159:11: error: binding reference of type ‘geometry_msgs::Vector3_<std::allocator<void> >::ConstPtr& {aka boost::shared_ptr<const geometry_msgs::Vector3_<std::allocator<void> > >&}’ to ‘const boost::shared_ptr<const geometry_msgs::Vector3_<std::allocator<void> > >’ discards qualifiers
           BOOST_FUNCTION_RETURN((*f)(BOOST_FUNCTION_ARGS));
           ^
gui_pkg/CMakeFiles/TCPSERVER.dir/build.make:62: recipe for target 'gui_pkg/CMakeFiles/TCPSERVER.dir/src/tcpserver.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [gui_pkg/CMakeFiles/TCPSERVER.dir/src/tcpserver.cpp.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1735: recipe for target 'gui_pkg/CMakeFiles/TCPSERVER.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [gui_pkg/CMakeFiles/TCPSERVER.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:140: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make -j4 -l4" failed
```

when i used the regular function callback as shown below, it works fine

```cpp
rand_dat1_sub_handle = node.subscribe<geometry_msgs::Vector3>(
        "random/data1", 100,
        &TCPServer::update_data1, this);
```

How do I use lamdas properly to represent callbacks in subscriber nodes?

I've edited the question showing the new errors after switching from `geometry_msgs::Vector3Ptr&` to `geometry_msgs::Vector3::ConstPtr&`.

Comment: Look at reference examples, in all cases callback takes its params by `const`, try `const geometry_msgs::Vector3Ptr& data` or even `const geometry_msgs::Vector3ConstPtr& data`.

Comment: yeah i used `geometry_msgs::Vector3::ConstPtr& data` as used in the subscriber script [here](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28c%2B%2B%29) but i continue to get the same errors. when i prefixed a `const` to `geometry_msgs::Vector3::ConstPtr& data`, then i get `call to member function subscribe is ambiguous` error from my IDE.